# SequelizeJS mapping stops on 1000th loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

This code needs to loop through 1050 items in an array and populate a products table in a postgres database. Unfortunately it stops at 1000 with no error. Does anyone know why this would happen?

```
import data from './data';

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('graphql', 'billy', '', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres',
  operatorsAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

const Data = sequelize.define('data', {
  name: Sequelize.TEXT,
});

// force: true will drop the table if it already exists
Data.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => {
    return data.map(d => {
      return Data.create({
        name: d.name,
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Model.bulkCreate` function instead of `Model.create`

```
Data.sync({force: true})
    .then(() => {
        const dataList = data.map( d => { name: d.name});
        return Data.bulKCreate(dataList).then( result => result);
    });
```